# Can ablution alleviate physical illness?

Tags: tafseer, hadith-interpretation

A brother was enduring terrible headache. He said Allah put a thought in his mind, of doing ablution. Immediately after ablution, he said "a huge relief"

Given we have reports saying ablution washes away sins. (Sahih Muslim)

another report saying if a Muslim is pricked by a thorn his sins are forgiven

And Quran telling And whatever difficulty (misfortune) befalls you, it is because of what your hands have earned 42:30.

Hence the question can ablution alleviate physical illness?